# How to keep the control on same page till text boxes got correct no. of characters?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have created two text boxes and wrote the JSfunction to give alert msg that both the boxes together should be of 50 characters. Function called in onclick() event in Submit button. Also in controller Store() function, save the content of these two text boxes and validated with "required", then  redirected to another page.
Problem is, if I give less than 50 characters it shows alert msg, but store the data even less than 50 characters given and redirected to specified page.
If i give less than 50 characters, after showing the alert msg, it has to be in the same page until i give together 50 characters. It should ave the textboxes content only if more than 50 characters. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please share you code using some editor for more clarity.

Comment: In your `onclick` function, don't allow the form to submit if the total value of characters from the two textboxes combined is less than `50`. Also add some validation in your controller that validates the number of characters passed from your view.